# how to get array record from a multidimensional array and save it in db

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How I can get each array record from a multidimensional array, print it and save it in mysql db with for or foreach loop, the size of array is unknown also.

```
Array (
[33] => Array ( [name] => A5 [status] => Busy [statusid] => 3 [num] => 33 ) 
[39] => Array ( [name] => A2 [status] => Available [statusid] => 1 [num] => 39 ) 
[55] => Array ( [name] => A3 [status] => Busy [statusid] => 3 [num] => 55 ) 
[54] => Array ( [name] => A4 [status] => Available [statusid] => 1 [num] => 54 ) 
)
```

Comment: Well, that's the beauty of a `foreach` loop, it starts at the beginning and works it's way to the end, so the length of the array doesn't really matter, now, show us what you have tried.

Comment: did u checked the given below solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size of array doesn't matter, you can use `foreach()`

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (name,status,statusid,num) VALUES ";
$data = array();
foreach ($YourArray as $key => $value) {
   $data[] = "('".$value['name']."','".$value['status']."','".$value['statusid']."','".$value['num']."')";
}
$query .= implode(",",$data);
echo $query;
```

Comment: @FQ: glad to help u